# Задержка определённой части кода

Tags: python-3.x

Как как сделать так, чтобы когда я делал `time.sleep(2)` не задерживался весь код, а только "определённая часть"?

Comment: Какая такая определённая часть? Вопрос непонятен

Comment: возможно `asyncio` исправит ситуацию